# Creating button for AS3 URL linkage. Getting Error: 1046

Tags: url, actionscript

I'm trying to create a button for my Flash game that links to my sites website.

However, I'm getting this error and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**Line 246 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: URLRequest.**

Here's some of my code from my Setup.as class

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent; 
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

public class Setup extends MovieClip {

    // For keeping things neat I removed my variables for this stack post. 

    public function Setup() {

        //..Preloader  
        loadingProgress = new LoadingProgress();
        loadingProgress.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        loadingProgress.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        addChild( loadingProgress );

        loaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, 
                                     onCompletelyDownloaded );
        loaderInfo.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, 
                                     onProgressMade );
        //..End Preloader
    }

   public function init():void {

        //Layer.init( stage );

        trace("");                      // Space Space Gotta Space This shiznit 
        trace("&& Game Initalized");    // Lets trace this MOFO 

        initStartup();
        //initLogo();
    }

    public function initStartup():void {
        drawGameStartup();
        btnJoyhype.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, urlRequestJoy );
    }
```

And then heres the URL Function

```
     public function urlRequestJoy( e:MouseEvent ) {
        var requestURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.myurl.com");
        navigateToURL( requestURL, "_blank" );
        trace("@@ Click Click");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message `Line 246 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: URLRequest.` indicates that he can't find the class `URLRequest`.

At the top of your class, you must import the class `URLRequest`, like this :

`import flash.net.URLRequest;`

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! Thanks a lot! :D I'll mark this the answer when Stack lets me. (says five minute wait right now).